# ListBox item from another ListBox

Tags: c#, listbox, windows-phone

On my Windows Phone app, i have two ListBox. I need that when keep an item pressed (from ListBox1), the item populates the ListBox2. 
So, my LisBox1 is populated from JSON (binding).

The code bellow doesn't works (Error: `Value does not fall within the expected range.`):

```
    public void addToList2(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        var dcs = ((FrameworkElement)sender).DataContext;
        Fields fi = (Fields)dcs;

        List2.Items.Add(fi);
    }
```

ListBoxes:

```
<ListBox Name="List1" Hold="addToList2" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}" Margin="0,85,0,0" >
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="242" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="128" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <StackPanel Margin="0,0,-62,17" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                                    <StackPanel.Background>
                                        <SolidColorBrush Color="#FF858585" Opacity="0.5"/>
                                    </StackPanel.Background>
                                    <TextBlock x:Name="NameTxt" Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding descricao}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="20" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding valor_preco_a, StringFormat=N2}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Margin="45,20,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" Text="{Binding codigo}" TextWrapping="Wrap" FontSize="35" Margin="370,-50,12,0" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextNormalStyle}" Foreground="Blue"/>

                                </StackPanel>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="R$" Margin="15,48,158,17" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextSubtleStyle}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
                            <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                        </Style>
                    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ListBox>

<ListBox Name="List2" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0,182,-66,0" Visibility="Collapsed">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel Margin="0,0,0,17" Width="432" Height="100">
                                <StackPanel.Background>
                                    <SolidColorBrush Color="#FFE8FF00" Opacity="0.2"/>
                                </StackPanel.Background>
                                <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding descricao}" TextWrapping="Wrap" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"/>

                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"

<Listbox x:Name="listbox1" ItemsSource="{Binding listOneObjects}" 
          SelectedItem="{listOneSelectedItem}" >
       <i:Interaction.Triggers>
               <i:EventTrigger EventName="PressAndHold">
                   <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding TouchDownCommand}"/>
               </i:EventTrigger>
       </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Listbox>

<Listbox x:Name="listbox2" ItemsSource="{Binding listTwoObjects, Mode=TwoWay}" 
         SelectedItem="{Binding listTwoSelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}">    
</Listbox>
```

Your C#

```
using System.ComponentModel;

public class YourClassName : INotifyPropertyChanged
    private List<Object> _listOneObjects;
    public List<Object> listOneObjects 
    {
        get{ return _listOneObjects; }
        set{ _listOneObjects = value; OnPropertyChanged("listOneObjects"); }
    }

private Object _listOneSelectedItem;
public Object listOneSelectedItem
{
    get{ return _listOneSelectedItem; }
    set{ _listOneSelectedItem = value;  OnPropertyChanged("listOneSelectedItem");  }
}


private List<Object> _listTwoObjects ;
public List<Object> listTwoObjects 
{
    get{ return _listOneObjects; }
    set{ _listOneObjects = value; OnPropertyChanged("listTwoObjects "); }
}

private Object _listTwoSelectedItem
public Object listTwoSelectedItem
{
    get{ return _listTwoSelectedItem; }
    set{ _listTwoSelectedItem= value; OnPropertyChanged("listTwoSelectedItem"); }
}

public ICommand TouchDownCommand{ get{ return _TouchDownCommand; }

private _TouchDownCommand;

public YourClassName(){
   this._TouchDownCommand= new ActionCommand(TouchDownExecuted);
}

private void TouchDownExecuted(){
   listTwoObjects.clear();
   listTwoObjects.Add(listOneSelectedItem);
   OnPropertyChanged("listTwoObjects");
}

PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

private void OnPropertyChanged(String prop){
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;

    if(handler != null)
    {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }

}
```

There are a number of moving parts here so you'll need to know the following.

1. Databinding
2. Command Binding
3. Interaction Triggers
4. Event Triggers
5. Binding Modes

Comment: But as I control, to send to ListBox2, only if holding the item (from ListBox1)?

Comment: You're english is pretty poor and I am having trouble understanding what you are saying. Are you saying that there is a collection in the item selected from listbox 1?

Comment: No, I need know, how this code XAML works with "keep pressed item". Sory for my bad english

Comment: because I don't understand how the ListBox1 item will be sent to ListBox2. Only touching an item?

Comment: You need to use command binding. Hang on I am working on an example

Answer (score -1):

```
object myItem;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        listBox1.Items.Add("Paul");
        listBox1.Items.Add("George");
        listBox1.Items.Add("Nik");
    }

    private void listBox1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {


        myItem = listBox1.SelectedItem;
        listBox2.Items.Add(myItem);
    }
```

Like that you can obtain whatever object is in listbox1 and show it in listbox 2. Just by clicking it with the mouse

Another answer is :

This is worth a read...

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx

SendKeys.Send("r")

This might just fire once, you may want to attach a timer that starts on the MouseDown event and stops on the MouseUp event. Then you could put the SendKeys in the Timer.Tick event.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.timer1.Interval = 500;
}

private void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs  e) 
{
    timer1.Stop();
    this.Text = "moose-Up";
}

private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    timer1.Start();
    this.Text = "moose-Down";
    this.richTextBox1.Select();
}

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SendKeys.Send("r");
    Debug.Print("tickling");
}
```

Select the control that you wish to receive the SendKeys value...

Comment: but I can't use "SelectedItem", because I have to use holding button action

Comment: So you want to repeatedly populate the second listbox with the same pressed value?

Comment: First off, there are no Forms in Windows Phone. I suggest you read up on WPF, XAML and Windows Phone prior to answering questions that involve XAML again. Second, this entire scenario should be handled in XAML. There is no reason for behind code. These days we attempt to follow MVVM pattern, especially with Windows Phone. Third, I would read about Binding. Data Binding, Input Binding, Command Binding ect. All of them. You'll see that using click events are antiquated.

Comment: Thanks for down grading

Comment: @Vla You're welcome for the downvote. However, it wasn't meant for you. It's meant to tell others that this is not the proper way to solve this problem. These answers are now kept as historic documented solutions to these problems. The last thing we want is to send future developers in the wrong direction with incorrect answers.

Comment: @Anthony Russell I see now. I should not have answered. I just want to build my reputation so I can positively vote. Therefore sometimes I want to answer question swiftly, so to be the first and receive the solved vote, without thinking two much what's the proper way to solve it .